# HorizontalScrollView with Linear Layout not scrolling with scrollTo, scrollBy

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout, horizontal-scrolling, horizontalscrollview

I can't make my HorizontalScrollView scroll to some X position, or by X pixels. It has a linear layout with buttons inside.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_room_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/roomsBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <!-- buttons -->

        </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Java:

```
buttonList = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_room_list);
//do stuff, at some point successfully save the scrolling offset with getScrollX()
barOffsetX = buttonList.getScrollX();
Log.e("x", "" + barOffsetX); //this prints a correct > 0 value
buttonList.scrollBy(barOffsetX, 0); //nothing happens, or
buttonList.scrollTo(barOffsetX, 0); //nothing happens
```

I think the problem may be about the LinearLayout. How can I make it scroll?

EDIT: I think the problem is about programmatically adding new buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined fixed with the child views or Linear layout like, Button view will accept 40 dp, so you can convert that dp-into-px with this method, and you an use returned value of this method .

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi / 160f);
    return px;
}
```

Comment: Sadly, whatever value I give to scrollBy(), scrollTo() doesn't change anything: the bar doesn't scroll. I forgot to mention a very important thing (I edited my question): the problem is that the buttons are added dinamically, from java. This prevent the bar from scrolling for some reason. For the moment I "solved" the issue by focusing the actual pressed button, but I don't like this solution because I'd like to restore the bar exactly as it was before a ConfigurationChange. Thanks for the answer, but the problem is not about the value.